# DatePicker is OneWay, but I need TwoWay

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datetimepicker

I have following DataGrid in wpf.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Name="adsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ads}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionChanged="adsGrid_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="File" Binding="{Binding Path=FileName}" IsReadOnly="True" />                
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Expiration date" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=ExpirationDate}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Info" Width="100*" Binding="{Binding Path=Info}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Problem is that DateTime picker won't update related object but will read value from it. I've tried adding Mode=TwoWay but it didn't help. Other properties are updated properly.

Comment: Does the output window say anything when you change the datepicker's value while debugging the application?

Comment: Nullability can cause blunders. Check if `DatePicker.SelectedDate` and `ExpirationDate` properties are match in type. If youare using any converter in between make sure its two way convertable. Also add `TwoWay` mode in the binding.

Comment: @AngelWPF They are, both are DateTime?

Comment: No mersadk `DatePicker.SelectedDate` is `Nullable<DateTime>`. I am not sure what your `ExpirationDate` property is. Is it `Nullable<DateTime>`? If so the two way binding without converter shoulld work just fine.

Comment: @AngelWPF ExpirationDate is "DateTime?" that is Nullable<DateTime>. But I can understand why my previous post is confusing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To debug this I would try:

1. Check the ExpirationDate property a `DateTime` (not a nullable or DateTimeOffset?)
2. Setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`
3. Adding a converter, and seeing if the converter is called

Comment: It is nullable, is that a problem? I've tried with converter, it's called when converting from object to wpf, but not in opposite direction.

Comment: Solution was to add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to binding